# How to appropriately use vartext in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to clean up my code. I currently have a long list of labels that are 'printed' if a certain condition is met. For example:

```
if 0000:
    output_0 = Label(frame_20, text="Condition 0 costs $15",
                     bg='white', padx=10, pady=10).grid(column=0,row=0)

if 0001:
    output_1 = Label(frame_20, text="Condition 1 costs $20",
                     bg='white', padx=10, pady=10).grid(column=0,row=0)
```

Ideally what I want is to separate the cost variable and the text entirely from the Label so that my code looks something like this:

```
if 0000:
    cost_0 = 15
    outputText = ("Condition 0 costs %d", cost_0)


if 0001:
    cost_1 = 20
    outputText = ("Condition 1 costs %d", cost_1)

output_x = Label(frame_20, vartext=outputText,
                 bg='white', padx=10, pady=10).grid(comumn=0,row=0)
```

Comment: I don't know where you're getting `vartext` from, the option would still be called `text=`.

Comment: Create a function that does this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are asking for some feature that you don't know yet - and also guessing you have way more conditions than your example.

For string formmating, use `f-string`. That is easiest, yet robust way to do so. For more details, check python [online](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) docs.

In a nutshell, it's used like this:

```py
a = 10
f" <any_text> {a} <even_more_text> "
```

About dynamic widget adding, forget about naming every label widget you created. Just iterate thru condition pairs and generate widgets, then store those in `list`.

```py
import tkinter
from typing import Iterable, Tuple, List

# List your conditions - expressions, bool, lambda, whatever in pair with associated value
conditions = (10 == 6, 15), (True, 20), (5, 25)


class App(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root_):
        super().__init__(root_)
        self.root = root_
        self.pack()

        # anything to store the reference - list, class, anything
        self.labels: List[tkinter.Label] = []

    def generate_labels(self, conditions_: Iterable[Tuple[bool, int]]):
        for idx, (condition, price_tag) in enumerate(conditions_):
            if condition:
                self.labels.append(tkinter.Label(self, text=f"Condition {idx} costs ${price_tag}"))

        for label in self.labels:
            label.pack()


root = tkinter.Tk()
app_reference = App(root)
app_reference.generate_labels(conditions)
root.mainloop()
```

And there's no such parameter `vartext` in `tkinter.Label`. I think you wanted to type `textvariable`.

If what you wanted is to have a *state* and checking if it matches the condition, then this will do:

```py
import tkinter


class App(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root_):
        super().__init__(root_)
        self.root = root_
        self.pack()

        self.solution_dict = {"0000": 15, "0001": 20, "0002": 25}
        self.label: tkinter.Label = None

    def get_solution(self, condition: str):
        if condition in self.solution_dict.keys():
            self.label = tkinter.Label(self, text=f"Condition {condition} costs ${self.solution_dict[condition]}")
            self.label.pack()


root = tkinter.Tk()
app_reference = App(root)
app_reference.get_solution("0001")
root.mainloop()
```

If there's more than one condition matching, try if dictionary key is inside the condition string.

```py
import tkinter
from typing import List


class App(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root_):
        super().__init__(root_)
        self.root = root_
        self.pack()

        self.solution_dict = {"0000": 15, "0001": 20, "0002": 25}
        self.labels: List[tkinter.Label] = []

    def get_solution(self, condition: str):
        for key in self.solution_dict.keys():
            if key in condition:

                widget = tkinter.Label(self, text=f"Condition {key} costs ${self.solution_dict[key]}")
                widget.pack()
                self.labels.append(widget)


root = tkinter.Tk()
app_reference = App(root)
app_reference.get_solution("0001 & 0002")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you jupiterbjy! The f-string is what I was looking for. Although the class example you have on here is even better, could you just help clarify the "conditions = (,)" part? In my code condition 0000 spits out one solution whereas condition 0001 suggests a different solution which is also a different price.  So my labels include the recommended solution AND price based on the conditions which I have translated into binary (0000, 0001, 0010, etc.)

Comment: Oh, so you have some variable and want to check-thru conditions for it - using a dictionary might be a good choice there, let me update my answer.